# How to plot a coordinate graph using plotly.Kt for y=1/x

Tags: kotlin, math, plotly

The goal is to plot the problems with dividing by zero using plotly:
The requirement is to draw a four quadrant coordinate graph and plot towards zero.

For equation y=1/x

x   | y

1   | 1

1/2 | 2

1/3 | 3

0   | -

-1/3| -3

-1/2|-2

-1  |-1

So far, I was able to draw the quadrant, but I want to plot the curved path or draw a line around.

```
fun main() {
    val trace1 = Scatter {
        x(-2, -1, -0, 1, 2)
        y(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
    }

    val plot = Plotly.plot {
        traces(trace1)

        layout {
            title = "Vertical and Horizontal Lines Positioned Relative to the Axes"
            xaxis {
                range = -2.0..2.0
            }
            yaxis {
                range = -9.0..9.0
            }

            width = 700
            height = 500

            shape {
                type = ShapeType.path
                x0 = Value.of(0.5)
                y0 = Value.of(2)
                x1 = Value.of(1)
                y1 = Value.of(1)
                line {
                    color("rgb(50, 171, 96)")
                    width = 4
                    dash = Dash.dot
                }
            }

        }
    }
    plot.makeFile()
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add different lines to each quadrant to draw y=1/x. For example, like this:

```
 val trace1 = Scatter {
    val range = -200..1
    x.numbers = range.map{ it.toDouble() / 100 }
    y.numbers = range.map{ 1 / (it.toDouble() / 100) }
    name = "negative"
}
val trace2 = Scatter {
    val range = 1..200
    x.numbers = range.map{ it.toDouble() / 100 }
    y.numbers = range.map{ 1 / (it.toDouble() / 100) }
    name = "positive"
}

val plot = Plotly.plot {
    traces(trace1, trace2)
    ...
}
plot.makeFile()
```

The result looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UqIUF.png).